# why vue component say there is not a variable in data?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

this is my Axios component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="comment">
            <div class="body">
                <p>{{fulluser.name}}</p>
            </div>

            <img class="image" :src="userimg" alt="" width="50px" height="50px">
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';
    export default {
        name: "commentcomponent",
        props:
        [
            "comment"
        ],
        data()
        {
            return{
                fulluser:null
            }
        },
        computed:
            {
                userimg()
                {
                    return "/images/"+this.fulluser.image;
                }
            },
        created() {
            // axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 5 });
            axios.get("/comment/userimage/"+this.comment.id)
                .then(res=>
                {
                    this.fulluser=res.data;
                    console.log(this.fulluser.id)

                })
        },
        methods:
            {
                userimg()
                {
                    return "/images/"+this.fulluser.image;
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

when I open the browser it works correctly but when I inspect it give me this error

> - app.js:44975 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read    property 'name' of null"

but it works in the browser and it gives me all images and names

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `axios` is asynchronous. That means the component is rendered before initializing `fulluser` value.
So you need to consider when `fulluser` is null even though it may be a short period.

```
<p>{{fulluser && fulluser.name || ''}}</p>
```

**Or**

```
data()
{
   return{
      fulluser: {
         name: ''
      }
   }
},
```

Comment: that problem fixed but now it say                                                                        Computed property "userimg" was assigned to but it has no setter